# Comparing HttpContext.User.Identity.Name

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4

I am trying this:

```
string username = httpContext.User.Identity.Name.ToString();
if (u.Equals(username))
{
    authorise = true;
}
```

the domain name and the username are exactly the same, letter for letter, backslash for backslash, capitals for capitals etc.. but the variable authorise is still false. Not sure why. I am beginning to wonder whether there is a way that is considered better practice for doing this.

Comment: what's the question?  you say they match and it's being set to true, that's what I'd expect.

Comment: @dove they match, but it is not set to true

Comment: okay, your question says otherwise

Comment: have you access to a testing framework?

Answer (score 0):

This maybe a mismatch of some kind.  I would write a unit test to verify your assumptions here.

The backslashes may be escaped differently.  You could try matching without these.

```
function string CleanAndTrim(string user){
    var cleaned = user.Replace(@"\", "");
    cleaned = user.Replace(@"/", "")
    return cleaned.ToLower().Trim();
}

if(CleanAndTrim(u)==CleanAndTrim(username){
  authorise = true;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Why are you calling `.ToString()` on a string?  And why are you using an if-statement to set a boolean value?  -- Assign the boolean directly. Try this:

```
string username = httpContext.User.Identity.Name;
authorise = u.Equals(username);
```

I wouldn't worry about best practices right now, as you need to get the basics down first.